# Unable to connect POSTGIS Table to CARTO

Tags: carto, carto-js

I am a new Carto Builder (enterprise) User and I am trying to connect a Postgres9.6.4 / PostgiS 2.3.1. table to my datasets.

Here is my script that should do the trick but I receive an extra long answer with html embeded code in it answering ERROR 500.

[image: curl import table line]
[image: API Error 500 Answer]

I tried to query the ?import/api to see if there was anything pending or processing but nothing.

Is PostgreSQL 9.6 supported ? PostGIS 2.3.1 ?

The table is 500Mo large, points, WGS 84.

Comment: how many rows does it have? because I have head that it may have a restriction on the number of rows in a table. maybe above 250,000 rows

Comment: Can you send this question to CARTO Enterprise support email? Disclaimer: I am Solutions Engineer at CARTO.

Comment: My table have 2millions rows. Thank you @ramiroaznar I already opened a ticket there. Seems 9.6 is not supported yet. I will have to try downgrade the postgres instance and then try again.

Comment: Can you point the source for that 250k rows limitation ? Thank you @ziggy

Comment: I have spoken a while back to somebody working at Carto. I'd confirm it with them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My table had too many rows (over a million). Carto does not support such large table. You need to split your table and merge in Carto SQL.

Thank you all for the support and answers

Answer (score 0):

```
curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ 
   "connector": {
    "provider": "postgres",
   "connection": {
      "server": "SERVERNAME",
      "database": "DB_NAME", 
      "username": "USERNAME", 
      "password": "PASSWORD"
     }, 
  "table" : "MY_TABLE"
   }, 

  "interval": 3600}' "https://documentation.carto.com/api/v1/imports/?
api_key=3102343c42da0f1ffe6014594acea8b1c4e7fd64"
```

I installed git bash, wrote the entire command as above in a text editor and pasted it at once into git bash. Note of advice, it's a lot more useful in the long run to modify the command to include an interval for the data to sync with your Postgres DB.